# Is it possible to start/stop/resume a redux-observable epic by emitting actions?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

This question may be about `redux-observable` or `rxjs` or both.

I'm looking for a way to start, stop or resume an epic through specific actions. For example, the epic (that's already part of the epic middelware) will be active when the action `{type: 'START'}` is received but will be inactive when the action `{type: 'END'}` is received. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of `switchMap` and `filter` to do this (assuming that all actions incl. the start/end-actions come from the same source)

If you start/end-actions are coming from a seperate source it is even easier, then you can skip the step of separating the source-stream.

Run the code-example below to see it in action.

```js
// this would be your source
const actions$ = new Rx.Subject();

// in this example controllActions and dataActions are derived from the same stream,
// if you have the chance to use 2 seperate channels from the start, do that
const controllActions$ = actions$
  .filter(action => action.type === "END" || action.type === "START");
const dataActions$ = actions$
  .filter(action => action.type !== "END" && action.type !== "START");

const epic$ = controllActions$
  .switchMap(action => {
    if (action.type === "END") {
      console.info("Pausing stream");
      return Rx.Observable.never();
    } else {
      console.info("Starting/Resuming stream");
      return dataActions$;
    }
  });
epic$.subscribe(console.log);

// simulating some action emissions, the code below is _not_ relevant for the actual implementation
Rx.Observable.from([
  "Some data, that will not be emitted...",
  {type: "START"},
  "Some data, that _will_ be emitted...",
  "Some more data, that _will_ be emitted...",
  {type: "END"},
  "Some data, that will not be emitted...",
  "Some data, that will not be emitted...",
  {type: "START"},
  "Some data, that _will_ be emitted...",
  "Some more data, that _will_ be emitted..."
])
  .concatMap(d => Rx.Observable.of(d).delay(400))
  .subscribe(actions$);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```